# How to get todays timespan from 00:00 till current time?

Tags: php, date, datetime

There is a lot to find about all different Date or Time calculations, but I was unable to locate the method to get exactly what I need.

I need to retrieve all history (traffic) from the database at any given time of day. I am using `$from` and `$till` for this. `$till` is easy because I fetch that with;

```
$till= new \DateTime();
```

wich shows as: **2014-06-05 16:21:53**

I need to fill `$from` with: **2014-06-05 00:00:00**

I think it will be very easy when I see the answer, but for now I am failing at achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just format `$till` with the time you desire:

```
$till= new \DateTime();
$from = $till->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FSdzpg)

You can also do:

```
$from = new \DateTime('midnight')
```

Comment: Exactly what I need! Two lines of simple code doing all the work, tnx!

Comment: You could also do this within your query depending on your specific requirements. For example, all of today's records could be retrieved with: "select * from table where `date` >= curdate()"

Comment: This is a massive database with millions of records so I need the method that will have the least query-load on the database. So anyone that can tell me wich method is the 'lightest' one please..

Comment: If you provide the date to MySQL it can take advantage of the index you have on your date column. That's the fastest way to perform the query.

Comment: By using the highest ID I can fetch the last 1440 objects (24 hour) in one grab and then filter them by date on the back-end. Thanks all for leading me to this combined solution!